# Socket Disconnect background Appcelerator

Tags: android, socket.io, appcelerator

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en android con socket.io y appcelerator, pero el problema que tengo es cuando la aplicación no esta visible en el dispositivo (en segundo plano) y el socket se desconecta. estoy entregando parametros cuando conecta el socket como: reconnect, delay etc. Pero no funciona.

Alguien ya trabajo con este tema que me ayude.

Saludos

Comment: Hola. Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ que ayude a comprender tu problema. Sigue esta guía _[ask]_.

Comment: Ejemplo no puedo mostrar, por que simplemente el socket se desconecta y la consola no muestra nada.